# Como informar a impressora para o Report Builder

Tags: delphi, report-builder

Utilizo o ReportBuilder em minhas aplicações e gostaria de saber como faço para informar qual a impressora ele utilizará para imprimir antes de exibir do relatório.

Comment: Eduardo, alterei sua pergunta. Veja se ainda está de acordo com o que você queria. Se não gostar ainda pode reverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução encontrada no DeveloperGuide do componente:

```
uses
  ppTypes;

ppReport1.DeviceType := dtPrinter;
ppReport1.Print;
```

Esse trecho exibe uma caixa de dialogo para que o usuário informe qual impressora deve ser usada.